# Object.observe on document.location

Tags: javascript, object.observe

I need to execute a js script when the hash of the page changes, I know there are many ways to know when the hash changes like using jQuery

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
   // do something
});
```

I tried to use the `Object.observe` but it didn't work, I just whant to know why it didn't, why the callback doesn't fire after updating the `document.location` object.

```
Object.observe(document.location, function(changes) { 
    console.log(changes);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.location along with many other DOM objects fall into the category of host objects which per spec do not have to behave like regular native JS objects.  While Object.observe may work for some of these objects, it does not behave reliably and happens not to work for document.location.

Another example where it does not work is:

```js
var el = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(el);
Object.observe(el, function(change) { console.log('changed ', change[0].name); })

el.id = "hello";
el.foo = "bar";
```

Comment: that makes sens. on your example, it works for the attribute `foo` but not `id` , I tried on `document.location` , it worked for a random attribute but not on `.hash`. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reasons you are not able to observe `document.location` using `Object.observe()` is because `document.location` returns an object of type `Location Object` (which is special read-only interface) and not "Standard" Object.

From Mozilla docs:

> The Document.location read-only property returns a Location object.
>   The location property of the Document object refers to the Location
>   object. Window.location is a read-only Location object.

Location interface:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Example:

```
console.log(document.location.__proto__); // returns Location {}
console.log(window.location.__proto__);   // returns Location {}
window.location === document.location // always true
```

The Object.observe() method is used for observing the changes to an object.

Example:

```
var o = { name: ''};
Object.observe(o, function(changes){
    changes.forEach(function(change) {
    console.log(change.type, change.name, change.oldValue);
});
});
o.name = 'foo'; // name is being observed
```

Look at the difference in their `__proto__`

```
console.log(document.location.__proto__); // returns Location {}
console.log(window.location.__proto__);   // returns Location {}
console.log(o.__proto__);                 // returns Object {}
```

Interesting enough if you test whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor you can get:

```
console.log(document.location instanceof Object); // true
console.log(o instanceof Object); // true
```

Code sample:

```js
var o = {
  name: ''
};
Object.observe(o, function(changes) {
  changes.forEach(function(change) {
    console.log(change.type, change.name, change.oldValue);
  });
});

o.name = 'foo';


console.log(document.location.__proto__); // returns Location {}
console.log(window.location.__proto__); // returns Location {}
console.log(o.__proto__); // returns Object {}


console.log(document.location instanceof Object); // true
console.log(o instanceof Object); // true
```

Comment: would you please read my post again ? I know I can't do it on `document.location.hash` , I did it on `document.location`. It doesn't return an error, but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think that's right - the original question is observing document.location rather than document.location.hash.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will double check, and I will edit my answer thanks for your comments ....